# How do I convert a 1 squaremeter to ping(0.3025) using scanner input and display output?

Tags: java

I know this is a very idiot question and I'm not supposed to ask for answer from you or neither this forum,I'm seriously google for hours to solve this,I actually get a kind of similar question to this which is Fahrenheit to Celsius,but that still not worked.

What I need is an example,by doing that I learn new things.

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Your question doesn't even make. I can't even. So much wat.

Comment: Wat. I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Ping is kinda like internet weak strong bar from what I know,that's what's the question ask.. So the thing I.was going to do is input scanner to get user input 50 squaremeter and then multiple to 0.3025 which is in ping then display the result output.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

- Create a scanner that could read from keyboard like `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`
- Read the input (assuming integer) using `nextInt` api and store it in a variable of type int like `int sqmts = scanner...`.
- Now print the statement using `System.out.println(sqmts + " sq mts = " + (number * 0.3025) + " pings")`

Comment: I will try it,currently at outside,thank you in advance.